# Dynamic Typecasting in Java

Tags: java, reflection, casting, bukkit

I'm writing a plugin for the Minecraft server implementation CraftBukkit, and I've come across a problem where I need to cast to a class that is found through reflection.

Here's the deal. The original code I wrote looked like this, with irrelevant parts removed:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.EntityAnimal;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.EntityHuman;
import org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.entity.CraftAnimals;
import org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.entity.CrafteEntity;

import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.entity.Animals;
import org.bukkit.entity.Entity;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;

public class Task extends BukkitRunnable {
    private static final int MATING_DISTANCE = 14;
    private final JavaPlugin plugin;
    private final Random randomizer;
    private boolean mateMode;
    private double chance;

    public Task(JavaPlugin plugin, double chance, boolean mateMode) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        this.randomizer = new Random();
        this.chance = chance;
        this.mateMode = mateMode;
        this.theTaskListener = listener;
    }

    public void run() {
        List<World> worlds = plugin.getServer().getWorlds();
        Iterator<World> worldIterator = worlds.iterator();

        while (worldIterator.hasNext()) {
            World world = worldIterator.next();
            Collection<Animals> animals = world.getEntitiesByClass(Animals.class);

            Iterator<Animals> animalIterator = animals.iterator();
            while (animalIterator.hasNext()) {
                Animals animal = (Animals) animalIterator.next();
                EntityAnimal entity = (EntityAnimal) ((CraftEntity) ((CraftAnimals) animal)).getHandle();
                EntityHuman feeder = null;
                entity.f(feeder);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, as you can see in the imports, this code imported the classes from only one version of the Minecraft server package - v1_7_R3. Now the problem is, I want to add support for more than that, and I want to be able to do that without creating separate versions of my plugin for each version of Minecraft. Despite the fact that most of the classes in the package are the same (at least ALL of those that I need) the package names are different, and therefore it can't be done with static imports (or at least I think so?)

So, I decided to use reflection in order to get the correct classes I need (this code is in another class):

```
private static final String[] requiredClasses = {
    "net.minecraft.server.%s.EntityAnimal",
    "net.minecraft.server.%s.EntityHuman",
    "org.bukkit.craftbukkit.%s.entity.CraftAnimals",
    "org.bukkit.craftbukkit.%s.entity.CraftEntity"
};
public static final String[] supportedVersions = {
    "v1_7_R3",
    "v1_7_R4"
};

public Class<?>[] initializeClasses() {
    String correctVersion = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < supportedVersions.length; i++) {
        String version = supportedVersions[i];
        boolean hadIssues = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < requiredClasses.length; j++) {
            String className = requiredClasses[j];
            try {
                Class.forName(String.format(className, version));
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                getLogger().log(Level.INFO, String.format("The correct version isn't %s.", version));
                hadIssues = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!hadIssues) {
            correctVersion = version;
            break;
        }
    }

    Class[] classes = new Class[requiredClasses.length];

    if (correctVersion != null) {
        getLogger().log(Level.INFO, String.format("The correct version is %s.", correctVersion));
        for (int i = 0; i < requiredClasses.length; i++) {
            String className = requiredClasses[i];
            try {
                classes[i] = Class.forName(String.format(className, correctVersion));
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
        }
    } else {
        getLogger().log(Level.WARNING, "The version of Minecraft on this server is not supported.");
        getLogger().log(Level.WARNING, "Due to this, the plugin will self-disable.");
        getLogger().log(Level.WARNING, "To fix this issue, get  build that supports your version.");
        this.setEnabled(false);
    }

    return classes;
}
```

Now, this approach successfully retrieves the required classes in both versions currently supported. I passed these to the rewritten Task class using instance variables and an edited constructor, and I removed the version-specific imports:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.entity.Animals;
import org.bukkit.entity.Entity;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;

public class Task extends BukkitRunnable {

    private static final int MATING_DISTANCE = 14;
    private final JavaPlugin plugin;
    private final Random randomizer;
    private boolean mateMode;
    private double chance;

    private Class entityAnimal;
    private Class entityHuman;
    private Class craftAnimals;
    private Class craftEntity;

    public Task(JavaPlugin plugin, Class[] classes, double chance, boolean mateMode) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        this.randomizer = new Random();
        this.chance = chance;
        this.mateMode = mateMode;

        this.entityAnimal = classes[0];
        this.entityHuman = classes[1];
        this.craftAnimals = classes[2];
        this.craftEntity = classes[3];
    }
```

Now, how can I rewrite the Task.run() method so that it will use the reflection classes? There is a whole lot of typecasting involved and unfortunately it's all necessary due to the ridiculous amount of overloading in the Minecraft code. For example, the entity.f(EntityHuman human) method cannot simply be called by doing entity.f(null) because there are other overloading entity.f(Object object) methods.

I am open to all suggestions as I'm facing a dead-end here. If there is a better approach to the problem, I could change to that as well.

Thank you!

Comment: -1 to *Minecraft server implementation Bukkit* for deliberately ignoring Java's [Naming a Package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) covention. And even worse, for polluting it with the version. Do you know the (maybe good) reason behind for doing such? I know, this doesn't help you in particular. See it as moral support (and, additionally, I wanted to be the frist to mention this, of course ;-). However, I'm going to see whether I can work out a more helpful answer.

Comment: I think it's done because the classes in two separate versions tend to be different and therefore cause plugins to fail in separate versions - this forces developers to review their plugins for every reason. It's definitely not the best way of doing this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading Gerold Broser's response, I realized that I would have to somehow modify my approach in order to create some sort of a handler class that would carry out the version-specific operation - of course this would be an interface that would separately be implemented by a class per version.

However, this became a problem when I realized Maven wouldn't let me call two versions of the same groupid.artifactid object.

I quickly did some research and found mbaxter's [Multiple Versions Tutorial](https://forums.bukkit.org/threads/support-multiple-minecraft-versions-with-abstraction-maven.115810/) as well as the [AbstractionExamplePlugin](https://github.com/mbax/AbstractionExamplePlugin) implementation which perfectly demonstrates this approach.

The approach works perfectly and is what every Bukkit developer should use. [Here](https://github.com/sultanskyman/WildSex)'s my finished plugin for further reference if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just a brainstorming idea. What if:

- importing all supported versions
- fully referencing the appropriate package's types
- checking for the version that's targeted at a particular runtime (assumed it can be obtained somehow)

  ```
  import net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.*;
  import net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.*;

  enum Version {
      V1_7_R3,
      V1_7_R4
  }

  Version currentVersion;

  net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.EntityAnimal animal3;
  net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.EntityAnimal animal4;

  // obtain currentVersion

  switch ( currentVersion ) {
      case V1_7_R3:
          animal3.method();
          break;
      case V1_7_R4:
          animal4.method();   
          break;
      }
  ```

This is somehow ugly, of course, but under the given circumstances it's the possibility that came into my mind first.

Answer (score 0):

In an object oriented language, we have access to various design patterns that have been developed for exactly this purpose. We use two patterns in particular.

[Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) is used to provide the same interface to a number of different implementations. It is sometimes called a shim. You create one class per version of each server, importing libraries to each. The class implements an interface that they hold in common.

[Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) is used to select among the adapter classes. You use whatever method you need to determine which server version you have, and it will create an object implementing the proper interface. The main code remains the same. It calls the factory to get an object that knows how to deal with the server.

The advantages of this approach are several. You don't pollute the name space by importing overlapping libraries. The main code is much less susceptible to change as new server versions are added; the only code that needs to be written is the new server shim and the factory that determines which adapter to produce.